# Cascading drop downs interfering with autocomplete textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a page with an Ajax Toolkit tab container, a pair of cascading drop downs, and an autocomplete textbox. When I first open the page, if I click on the autocomplete textbox, the list of words/phrases drops down immediately. If I then click the first of the drop downs and then go back and click in the autocomplete textbox, nothing happens in that textbox. The words/phrases do not drop down. Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening, and how to make it not happen?

In the aspx:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    BindControls();
});
function BindControls() {
    $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "ServiceCS.asmx/GetScopes",
                data: "{ 'sLookUP': '" + request.term + "' }",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item,
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            $("#<%=txtScopeID.ClientID%>").val(i.item.value);
        },
        minLength: 0,
        scroll: true
    }).focus(function(){
        $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
    })
}
</script>
...
<ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" 
    TabStripPlacement="Top">
<ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" ID="JobPanel" HeaderText="Job Info">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="right_column">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClient" AutoPostBack="true" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlClient_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="cddlClient" runat="server" 
        Category="ClientID" LoadingText="Loading..." 
        PromptText="Select Client" ServiceMethod="GetClients" 
        ServicePath="~/ServiceCS.asmx" TargetControlID="ddlClient">
    </ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown>
</td>
<td class="right_column">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLoc" AutoPostBack="true" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLoc_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="cdlLocs" runat="server" 
        Category="ClientLocationID" LoadingText="Loading..." 
        ParentControlID="ddlClient" PromptText="Select Location" 
        PromptValue="" ServiceMethod="GetLocations" 
        ServicePath="~/ServiceCS.asmx" TargetControlID="ddlLoc">
    </ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="right_column">
    <input type="text" value="" id="txtSearch" style="text-align:left; 
        width:300px;" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</ContentTemplate>
</ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
</ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
```

Services.asmx:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetClients(knownCategoryValues As String) As CascadingDropDownNameValue()
    Dim query As String = "SELECT ClientCode + ' | ' + ClientName"
    query &= "     , ClientID"
    query &= "  FROM view_ClientCombo"
    query &= " ORDER BY ClientCode"
    Dim clients As List(Of CascadingDropDownNameValue) = GetData(query)
    Return clients.ToArray()
End Function

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetLocations(knownCategoryValues As String) As CascadingDropDownNameValue()
    Dim client As String = CascadingDropDown.ParseKnownCategoryValuesString(knownCategoryValues)("ClientId")
    'Dim query As String = String.Format("SELECT CliLocNumber FROM view_ClientLocation WHERE ClientID = {0}", client)
    Dim query As String = String.Format("SELECT CliLocNumber + ' | ' + CliLocCity + ' | ' + CliLocState, replace(CliLocName, '''', '''''') FROM dbo.view_ClientLocCombo WHERE ClientID = {0}", client)
    Dim locations As List(Of CascadingDropDownNameValue) = GetData(query)
    Return locations.ToArray()
End Function

Private Function GetData(query As String) As List(Of CascadingDropDownNameValue)
    Dim conString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query)
    Dim values As New List(Of CascadingDropDownNameValue)()
    Using con As New SqlConnection(conString)
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While reader.Read()
                values.Add(New CascadingDropDownNameValue() With { _
                 .name = reader(0).ToString(), _
                 .value = reader(1).ToString() _
                })
            End While
            reader.Close()
            con.Close()
            Return values
        End Using
    End Using
End Function

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetScopes(ByVal sLookUP As String) As String()
    Dim scopes As New List(Of String)()
    Using conn As New SqlConnection()
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT JobScopeDesc + ' | ' + JobScopeID AS JobScopeDesc FROM view_JobScopeCode where JobScopeDesc like '%' + @SearchText + '%' ORDER BY JobScopeDesc"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", sLookUP)
            cmd.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While sdr.Read()
                    scopes.Add(sdr("JobScopeDesc").ToString())
                End While
            End Using
            conn.Close()
        End Using
        Return scopes.ToArray()
    End Using
End Function
```

I've never used web methods or Jquery, I found these examples and made them work for me -- until I noticed this problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your cascading dropdowns are set up to postback when the values change and this causes the page to refresh but your `BindControls()` function is not being rerun. This happens because the postback is a "Partial Page Update" and the DOM is not refreshed for this type of update. Therefore your `$(document).ready` function is not executed after postback and your autocomplete textbox appears to be broken. See this page for more information on partial page updates: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax.

The question here is, are you doing anything in the server-side code (`ddlClient_SelectedIndexChanged` and `ddlLoc_SelectedIndexChanged` functions) that requires you to postback after selecting a value in the dropdown? If not, then you can just disable the postback functionality by rewriting your dropdown fields like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClient" AutoPostBack="false" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

and:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLoc" AutoPostBack="false" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

If you do have a need to keep the postback in there then you simply need to ensure that your `BindControls()` function is run after a partial page update. To do this you can add a page request manager line above your `$(document).ready` function which calls the BindControls function on partial page update:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(BindControls);
```

Comment: The only things done server-side are filling the drop downs from the web methods and then getting the selected values in the code-behind. I'm really new to Javascript, Jquery, and web methods, so thank you for the link. I'll read that and try your suggestions and let you know how it goes.

Comment: The filling of the drop downs is done via ajax (ajaxtoolkit with the `ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown` elements calls the code-behind from your web service `ServiceCS.asmx`) and doesn't require a postback which is the whole point of ajax. It sounds like your `ddlClient_SelectedIndexChanged` and `ddlLoc_SelectedIndexChanged` functions in the code-behind are empty. If this is the case, I recommend my first approach as doing the postback causes unnecessary headaches like the issue you are experiencing if you do not have a specific need to do so.

Comment: That did it! I took out the autopostback = "true" and it works! *whew* Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a shot in the dark, but you might try stripping off the `focus()` handler.

i.e. replacing this last chunk

```
}).focus(function(){
    $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
});
```

with this:

```
});
```

I suggest this because the code inside that block (`$(this).autocomplete("search", "");`) seems to be undoing the work of the first `.autocomplete()` call in your code (i.e. the stuff that starts with `$("#txtSearch").autocomplete({` ).

I say that the code inside the `focus()` handler might be undoing the work of the first `autocomplete()` call because I can't see or tell what "search" refers to, and the second argument being an empty string doesn't seem to bode well.  The autocomplete jQuery widget takes an event and ui for its arguments to `autocomplete()`, so having a blank string for the ui param and an unknown name for event *might* explain why the list no longer appears.

Anyway, something to try!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it didn't work. The first time you click in that textbox, the suggestions don't drop down until you hit the Alt key. Any time after that, nothing.